# validate a Jexl script under "compile" terms?

Tags: java, jsr223, jexl

See this example:

```
public class JexlStuff {

    private static final JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().cache(512).strict(true).silent(false)
            .safe(true).create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JexlScript script = jexl.createScript("var x ='6'; ");

        // populate the context
        JexlContext context = new MapContext();

        Object result = script.execute(context);
        System.out.println(result);
        if (result != null)
            System.out.println(result.getClass());

    }
}
```

This example prints "6" (why?). But there is no `return` statement. Is it some kind of configuration that will make the above example throw an error, since the script provided could never be "compiled"?

Best scenario for me, this line throws an error:

```
JexlScript script = jexl.createScript("var x ='6'; ");
```

Is there a way to validate - check syntax of the given script?

FYI:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jexl is a **scripting** (JSR223) language,

`var x ='6';` is a valid **script**, so no invalid compilation should be thrown

When setting value in script's last line the results is the output, for example in Jexl (github) [test](https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/jexl3/introspection/SandboxTest.java)

> ```
> final JexlEngine sjexl = new JexlBuilder().sandbox(sandbox).safe(false).strict(true).create();
> final JexlScript set = sjexl.createScript("foo[x] = y", "foo", "x", "y");
> result = set.execute(null, foo, 0, "42");
> Assert.assertEquals("42", result);
> ```